# From .deb to xcode Project

Tags: ios, xcode

Sorry in advance if i misunderstand the concept.

I have a project and it is Git in a private server. I have been told to have a release history like they do with the android project where they store the APK for each release in another server.

I have been been looking how to achieve the same on iOS and I generated the IPA and the .deb file and I have stored them.

My questions are:

1. What does the .deb file mean?
2. Can I restore the xcode project from the .deb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .deb file is just an [archived version](https://www.geekcosmos.com/how-to-convert-deb-file-ipa-app-sideloading-ios/) of the app's binary. You should be able to extract the .ipa from the .deb. You will not be able to restore an Xcode project from either of the the files as they are compiled code.